# Green's Theorem: Condition on the curve $C$?

Tags: greens-theorem

In many sources, the condition of Green's Theorem lists the curve $C$ as a piece-wise smooth curve. Isn't it enough for $C$ to be a piece-wise $C^1$ curve? Or does "piece-wise smooth curve" understood to be $C^1$?

Comment: Yes, smooth paths are usually defined as $C^1$ paths (as opposed to the stronger $C^\infty$ requirement), but it's best to check the source's definitions, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $C$ is a closed curve, as required for Green's theorem. The term 'piecewise' refers to the possibility that $C$ is made up from, say, 'subcurves'. Think of the meaning of 'piecewise function' for example. The same concept applies here. 
Consider if $C$ was a circular path - split it, let's say, into 2 parts, then we say $C$ is a combination of $C_1$ and $C_2$, the upper half and the lower half. However, make sure they are traversed the same way! $$C=C_1 \cup C_2 \cup \dots \cup C_{n-2}\cup C_{n-1}\cup C_{n}$$ 
Hopefully this helps!